# Using SSRS line charts to graph time periods on the y-axis

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I am looking to to use an SSRS line chart to graph ending run times of jobs.  I am using runtime on the y-axis and date on the x-axis.  The graph looks like a flat line and the times do not show up on the y-axis, but integers show.

I also want to put a target line at a specific time to show our SLA time.

Here is example of data I am trying to graph, but I want a line.

```
+-------+----------+
|   y   |    x     |
+-------+----------+
| 10:05 | 3/1/2009 |
| 11:00 | 3/2/2009 |
| 10:15 | 3/3/2009 |
+-------+----------+

+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| 11:00 |          |    x     |          |
| 10:45 |          |          |          |
| 10:30 |          |          |          |
| 10:15 |          |          |    x     |
| 10:00 |    x     |          |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
|       | 3/1/2009 | 3/2/2009 | 3/3/2009 |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi Lori, what version of SSRS are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Lets say you have table Times with Date and Hours. 
Declare Report parameter @LimitHourParam decimal - for target time.
Set query of dataset:

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Hours) AS Hours, 'Actual Hours' AS LimitHour
FROM Times 
GROUP BY Date
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT Date, @LimitHourParam AS Hours, 'Hours Limit' AS LimitHour
FROM Times
```

So you will get in result hours grouped by dates and some hour limit for unique each date.

Place Chart control in report page.

Go to Chart Properties->Data

Press "Add Values"
Erase value of Label and set Value to

```
=Sum(Fields!Hours.Value)
```

Go to "Point Labels" tab of "Edit Chart Value" dialog, check "Show point labels", set   Data label to

```
= String.Format("{0}:{1}",  (Fields!Hours.Value / 1) - (Fields!Hours.Value Mod 1), (Fields!Hours.Value Mod 1)*60/1 - (Fields!Hours.Value Mod 1)*60 Mod 1)
```

Add Category Groups, set "Group On" expression to

```
=Fields!Date.Value
```

Add Series Group, set both "Group On" expression and Label values to

```
=Fields!LimitHour.Value
```

Go to Chart Properties->X Axis, set labels format dd/mm/yyyy

Result should look like this:
[image: http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/3838/ssrschart.jpg]